# A determinantal inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

The following is an exercise from the 2023 international selection at [École Normale Supérieure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_normale_sup%C3%A9rieure_(Paris)) (ENS):

> Prove that for any complex numbers $a_1, \dots, a_n$ and positive semi-definite complex matrices $A_1, \dots ,A_n$ , the following inequality is satisfied: $$ \det \left( \left| a_1 \right| A_{1\ } + \left| a_2 \right| A_2 + \dots + \left| a_n \right| A_n \right) \geq | \det(a_1 A_1 + \dots + a_n A_n)| $$

---

So far, I have tried using the [Hadamard inequality on determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality) but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere. Same for expanding the determinant using the permutations formula.

Since it's an exercise from ENS, it is supposed to be somehow hard and I don't know how to "start". The exercises from ENS are known to be very hard to approach since it's literally the best mathematics department of France. Any hints, please?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_k$ be $m\times m$. By splitting each $A_k$ into a sum of rank-one positive semidefinite matrices, you may assume that each $A_k$ is rank-one. In this case, if $m>n$, then both sides are zero and we have nothing to prove. Suppose $m\le n$. Let $A_k=x_kx_k^\ast$, $D=\operatorname{diag}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(|a_1|,|a_2|,\ldots,|a_n|)$. By Cauchy-Binet formula,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&|\det(a_1A_1+\cdots+a_nA_n)|\\
&=|\det(XDX^\ast)|\\
&=\left|\,\sum_{S\in\binom{[n]}{m}}\det\left(X_{[m],S}\,(DX^\ast)_{S,[m]}\right)\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\sum_{S\in\binom{[n]}{m}}\det\left(X_{[m],S}\,D_{S,S}\,(X^\ast)_{S,[m]}\right)\,\right|\quad\text{(because $D$ is diagonal)}\\
&\le\sum_{S\in\binom{[n]}{m}}\left|\,\det\left(X_{[m],S}\,D_{S,S}\,(X^\ast)_{S,[m]}\right)\,\right|\quad\text{(triangle inequality)}\\
&=\sum_{S\in\binom{[n]}{m}}\det\left(X_{[m],S}\,|D|_{S,S}\,(X^\ast)_{S,[m]}\right)\quad\text{(because $|\det D_{S,S}|=\det|D|_{S,S}$)}\\
&=\sum_{S\in\binom{[n]}{m}}\det\left(X_{[m],S}\,(|D|X^\ast)_{S,[m]}\right)\quad\text{(because $|D|$ is diagonal)}\\
&=\det\left(X\,|D|\,X^\ast\right)\\
&=\det\left(|a_1|A_1+\cdots+|a_n|A_n\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
So, the inequality in question is basically the triangle inequality in disguise.

Comment: okkk i got it, basically you said that the matrice $a_1 A_1 + ... + a_n A_n$ is also of dimension $m \times m$ with complex coefficients, so it is in fact diagonalizable in C right ?

Comment: @LéoFabrègues No, this has nothing to do with diagonalisation. E.g. if $A_1$ is of rank $3$ and $A_2$ is of rank $2$, we may write $A_1=x_1x_1^\ast+x_2x_2^\ast+x_3x_3^\ast$ and $A_2=x_4x_4^\ast+x_5x_5^\ast$ for some appropriate $x_j$s. Therefore $$a_1A_1+a_2A_2=\pmatrix{x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5}\pmatrix{a_1\\ &a_1\\ &&a_1\\ &&&a_2\\ &&&&a_2}\pmatrix{x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5}^\ast.$$

Comment: If you don't like this perspective using rank-one matrices, you may also write $\sum_{k=1}^na_kA_k$ as $$\pmatrix{\sqrt{A_1}&\cdots&\sqrt{A_n}}\pmatrix{a_1I\\ &\ddots\\ &&a_nI}\pmatrix{\sqrt{A_1}\\ \vdots\\ \sqrt{A_n}}.$$ The current proof can still be applied with slight modifications (mostly about the sizes of the matrices).

Answer (score 5):

I assume the matrices $A_i$ are in $\Bbb C^{d\times d}$.
Let $M:=a_1A_1+\cdots+a_nA_n$ and $N:=|a_1|A_1+\cdots+|a_n|A_n$.

- Suppose $N$ is invertible (so positive definite). The goal is to show $\det N\ge|{\det M}|$, likewise $$\lvert{\det(N^{-1}M)}\rvert\le 1.$$
  It then suffices to show that any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $N^{-1}M$ has $|\lambda|\le1$. Let $x\neq0$ be an associated eigenvector. Then $N^{-1}Mx=\lambda x$, so $Mx=\lambda Nx$ and
  $$|\lambda|\,x^*Nx=|x^*Mx|=\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^na_i\,x^*A_ix\right\rvert\le\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|\,|x^*A_ix|=\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|\,x^*A_ix=x^*Nx,$$
  which shows that $|\lambda|\le1$.
- If $N$ is not invertible, there still exists a sequence $\varepsilon_k\searrow0$ such that $N+\varepsilon_k\,I_d$ is positive definite. Then
  $$\det(|a_1|A_1+\cdots+|a_n|A_n+\varepsilon_k\, I_d)\ge\left\lvert{\det(a_1A_1+\cdots+a_nA_n+\varepsilon_k\,I_d)}\right\rvert$$ by the previous point. Letting $k\to\infty$ yields $$\det(|a_1|A_1+\cdots+|a_n|A_n)\ge\left\lvert{\det(a_1A_1+\cdots+a_nA_n)}\right\rvert$$ by continuity of the determinant.

Comment: waaah i totally get it, thank you! however it wasn't a hint HAHA